# How to type cast elements of uint32 array before modulo operation?

Tags: c, arrays, casting, modulo

I am forced to store output in an `unsigned int` array.  However, the output is the solution to a linear combination of previous elements in the array *modulo* 2147483647, that is *modulo* 2^31-1.

Below is a code snippet from a larger function.  Quickly, this snippet will yield wrong answers as `ii` wraps around the index of `xx`.  (Note that `xx` is seeded before the function is called, so that no element in the array is empty.)

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unit_least64_t uint64;
static uint32 xx[47];

...

xx[ii] = 12345 * (uint64)(xx[i0] + xx[ii]) % 2147483647;  // i0, ii are defined elsewhere
```

However, if we swap the last line with the following, we will continually get the correct solution.

```
xx[ii] = 12345 * ( (uint64)xx[i0] + (uint64)xx[ii] ) % 2147483647;
```

Perhaps, it is obvious, but why is it necessary to do two typecasts to unit64 instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One type cast should be enough, as long as you put it at the right place:

```
xx[ii] = 12345 * ( (uint64)xx[i0] + xx[ii] ) % 2147483647;
```

The important thing is to cast before the addition to prevent numeric overflows, not after it, when the overflow has already happened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your initial code can be written like that:

```
uint32 t1 = xx[i0] + xx[ii]; // problem is here, result of sum is truncated as it is 32 bit
uint64 t2 = (uint64)t1;
uint64 t3 = 12345 * t2 % 2147483647;
xx[ii] = (uint32)t3;
```

if you go with second variant, you will have:

```
uint64 t0 = (uint64)xx[i0];
uint64 t1 = (uint64)xx[ii];
uint64 t2 = t0 + t1; // no truncation, as the result is 64 bit
uint64 t3 = 12345 * t2 % 2147483647;
xx[ii] = (uint32)t3;
```